# How to send output of previous programme in pipe to the next programme correctly?

Tags: c, unix

> The goal is to implement terminal command **prog1 > file && prog2 | prog3** given the arguments `prog1`, `file`, `prog2` and `prog3`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd,status,pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);
    /* S_IRWXU - full acces to file */
    fd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
if (!fork()){
    dup2(fd, 1); /* redirection to file */
    close(fd); /* it's useless now */
    execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
}
else {
    wait(&status);
    if (!status){
        if (fork()){
            dup2(pipefd[1],1);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            execlp(argv[3], argv[3],NULL);
        }
    wait(NULL);
    dup2(pipefd[0],0);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execlp(argv[4], argv[4],NULL);  
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I can't make this code to show data that last programme got from previous one.
For example (assume programme's name is `prog`):

```
./prog ps f date echo
```

doesn't show current date. And I don't understand why.  Can you explain?

Comment: "Conveer"? Do you mean "pipe"?

Comment: yes, of course. It's local name that I got used to

Comment: You shouldn't open the pipe until after you `wait()` on the first program completing.  You should indent your code better.  You should report an error and explicitly exit if `execlp` returns (it only ever returns on an error; you don't need to test the return value). You should not wait for one of the programs to finish before starting the other; you can get deadlock that way (if the first program in the pipeline generates more data than fits in a pipe buffer, which is finite and often either 5 KiB or 64 KiB).

Comment: Note that `date | echo` at the shell produces a newline in the output; the date does not appear.  You'd replace `echo` with `cat` (for instance) to see the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run:

```
date | echo
```

at the command line prompt of a shell, you will get a newline and no date.  Change `echo` to `cat` and you will see the date:

```
$ date | echo

$ date | cat
Mon Dec 11 16:35:54 PST 2017
$
```

You could fix your code so it works better on errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s prog1 file prog2 prog3\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to fork\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* S_IRWXU - full access to file */
        int fd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for writing\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
            return 1;
        }
        dup2(fd, 1); /* redirection to file */
        close(fd);   /* it's not needed now */
        execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        if (status == 0)
        {
            int pipefd[2];
            pipe(pipefd);       // Error check?
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to fork\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                close(pipefd[0]);
                execlp(argv[3], argv[3], NULL);
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s\n", argv[0], argv[3]);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
                close(pipefd[0]);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                execlp(argv[4], argv[4], NULL);
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute %s\n", argv[0], argv[4]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A lot of C programming is about error handling.  Having a function library that makes error reporting simpler helps enormously.  For example, I have a library with header file `stderr.h` and implementation in `stderr.c` — source available from [GitHub](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq).  It simplifies (and improves) the error reporting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    if (argc != 5)
        err_usage("prog1 file prog2 prog3");
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork: ");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        /* S_IRWXU - full access to file */
        int fd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
        if (fd < 0)
            err_syserr("failed to open file %s for writing: ", argv[2]);
        dup2(fd, 1); /* redirection to file */
        close(fd);   /* it's not needed now */
        execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        int status;
        wait(&status);
        if (status == 0)
        {
            int pipefd[2];
            pipe(pipefd);       // Error check?
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
                err_syserr("failed to fork");
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                close(pipefd[0]);
                execlp(argv[3], argv[3], NULL);
                err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", argv[3]);
            }
            else
            {
                dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
                close(pipefd[0]);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                execlp(argv[4], argv[4], NULL);
                err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", argv[4]);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example, the `err_syserr()` function reports the system error number and message as well as the command name (`prog41`) and the message specified in the call.  (And yes, there are ways to compress both programs a bit more — the `else` on the outer `if` block could be removed, leaving the following code one level less indented (and the code three lines shorter), for example.)

This program was `prog41`, and the test output could be:

```
$ ./prog41 rigmarole /dev/not-there fudge pumpkin
prog41: failed to open file /dev/not-there for writing: error (1) Operation not permitted
$ ./prog41 rigmarole not-there fudge pumpkin
prog41: failed to execute rigmarole: error (2) No such file or directory
$ ./prog41 ps not-there fudge pumpkin
prog41: failed to execute pumpkin: error (2) No such file or directory
prog41: failed to execute fudge: error (2) No such file or directory
$ ./prog41 ps not-there date pumpkin
prog41: failed to execute pumpkin: error (2) No such file or directory
$ ./prog41 ps not-there date cat
Mon Dec 11 16:49:11 PST 2017
$ ./prog41 proxy mangler
Usage: prog41 prog1 file prog2 prog3
$
```

After running the program successfully, the file `not-there` was there, of course.

Answer (score -1):

You have three exec's, but 2 forks. I personally would do three forks (one for each exec), and have 2 pipes to communicate within the processes.

Comment: What would the second pipe do other than confuse things?  Why the third fork?  There doesn't seem to be a requirement for the initial process to catch statuses and report them.