# How to use fork() to run 3 commands in C?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, execvp

I have to implement code that will run a certain number of executables (ex. grep, echo, etc.) at the same time (concurrently). The executables will be given as a string, which I have parsed. The requirement of the code is that the output of one executable is the input of another.

I am trying to understand how to implement this when there is an odd number of executables. To my knowledge the fork function will replicate the code at hand. If I put my code as such:

```
for(int I=0; I<3; I++){
     pid_t pid = fork();
}
```

then when `I==0`, 1 child will be produced. When `I==1`, 2 children will be produce, and similarly, when `I==2`, 4 children will be produced. If I was to only allow execution to happen in the child (when `pid==0`), I would still have a total of 7 executions, which is 4 more than I need.

Comment: All of the child processes in the pipeline should be siblings; there should be no parent/child relationship between them.

Comment: [How to send output of previous programme in pipe to the next programme correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761806/how-to-send-output-of-previous-programme-in-pipe-to-the-next-programme-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

What could be happening

```
1) parent creates 3 children child1(i=0), child2(i=1), child3(i=2)
2) child1 creates 2 children child4 (i=1), child5(i=2)
3) child2 creates 1 child child6 (i=2)
4) child4 creates 1 child child7 (i=2)
```

To get around this, first note what the parent pid is

```
pid_t parent = getpid();
```

Then create the children

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++ii)
{
    pit_t child = fork();
```

If it is not the parent, break out

```
    if (child != parent) break;
}
```

You now have one parent and 3 children.